# Footer pushes up to resize image in Content div

Tags: html, css, resize, liquid

I am trying to create a simple layout in which there would be:

HEADER

CONTENT (image here)

FOOTER

What I am trying to achieve is to have an image placed inside the content div that will resize larger and smaller based on the browser size of the viewer.

This part I can achieve, however I would like the footer to always remain at the bottom of the browser and have the image in the content div resize without ever creating overflow.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:
http://www.modernart.net/view.html?id=1,3,9

I have tried replicating this code but cannot make it work. 
Is there a way that anyone can suggest to do this?
I would be extemely helpful as I have had no luck making it work so far.

Thanks in advance,
Takashi

Comment: Just take a look at the [css for that site](http://www.modernart.net/GLOBAL/global.js)

Comment: Thanks vascowhite.
Yes - as I mentioned when posting my question I have replicated the code from that site - css and html. 

However I cannot make it work for my layout. 

The main part that I cannot achieve is to have the image resize so there is no overflow creating a scroll and that the footer is always in screen below the image.

If you can suggest a way to do this it would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You could try to use a Sticky Footer. Google for CSS Sticky Footer. Use @ for you messages.

Comment: @Jawad. Thanks for your suggestion. I have actually tried this - however the image just ends up underneath the footer. 

I basically need the footer to always be at the bottom of the bowser (in the same vein as a sticky footer) but force the content image to resize instead of creating overflow.

Comment: I am using Google Chrome 18.0.1025.168 as my browser and MAC OS X Version 10.6.8.

Answer (score 0):

Using percentages with css could be a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/rgv2e/

Answer (score 0):

You really should try to do things and learn by your mistakes. Nonetheless, here's the layout you're after:

**See this** [Working Fiddle Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/BH7y2/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">My Beautiful website!</div>
<div id="content">
  <a href="#" title="">
    <img src="http://i328.photobucket.com/albums/l330/slowwkidd3923/backflip.jpg" alt="ups...">
  </a>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  This is the footer text!
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* basics */
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* header */
#header {
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}

/* content */
#content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
#content img {
    height: 96%;
}

/* footer */
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

---

### Links to help you learn CSS:

[Cascading Style Sheets](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/)

[Cascading Style Sheets Level 2 Revision 1 (CSS 2.1) Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/CR-CSS2-20090908/)

[MDN :: CSS - References, Tutorials and Demos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS)